# Need Debug React Client to NodeJS Server to MySQL DB 404 Error After CORS Config

Tags: node.js, reactjs, client

I've created a front end client in React with a form that is using Axios to submit data to the backend nodejs server api but after setting up CORS I get a 404 error from Axios.

The MySQL database submission from the backend has already been tested as working, but after installing CORS, and customizing the configuration for the client app at localhost:3000 to request the server-side at localhost:3030 but now the client app returns a 404 error in console.

Here is the error response from the console log:

```
:3030/user-create:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) AxiosErrorcode: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"config: adapter: ƒ xhrAdapter(config)data: "{\"referBy\":\"asdfasdf\",\"referId\":\"0qCsT_2y3\",\"eMail\":\"asdfasdf\"}"env: {FormData: null}headers: Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"Content-Type: "application/json"[[Prototype]]: ObjectmaxBodyLength: -1maxContentLength: -1method: "post"timeout: 0transformRequest: [ƒ]transformResponse: [ƒ]transitional: {silentJSONParsing: true, forcedJSONParsing: true, clarifyTimeoutError: false}url: "http://localhost:3030/user-create"validateStatus: ƒ validateStatus(status)xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN"xsrfHeaderName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN"[[Prototype]]: Objectmessage: "Request failed with status code 404"name: "AxiosError"request: XMLHttpRequestonabort: ƒ handleAbort()onerror: ƒ handleError()onload: nullonloadend: ƒ onloadend()onloadstart: nullonprogress: nullonreadystatechange: nullontimeout: ƒ handleTimeout()readyState: 4response: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Cannot POST /user-create</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n"responseText: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Cannot POST /user-create</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n"responseType: ""responseURL: "http://localhost:3030/user-create"responseXML: nullstatus: 404statusText: "Not Found"timeout: 0upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload {onloadstart: null, onprogress: null, onabort: null, onerror: null, onload: null, …}withCredentials: false[[Prototype]]: XMLHttpRequestresponse: config: {transitional: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, adapter: ƒ, …}data: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Cannot POST /user-create</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n"headers: content-length: "151"content-type: "text/html; charset=utf-8"[[Prototype]]: Objectconstructor: ƒ Object()hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()toString: ƒ toString()valueOf: ƒ valueOf()__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()__proto__: (...)get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()request: XMLHttpRequestonabort: ƒ handleAbort()onerror: ƒ handleError()onload: nullonloadend: ƒ onloadend()onloadstart: nullonprogress: nullonreadystatechange: nullontimeout: ƒ handleTimeout()readyState: 4response: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Cannot POST /user-create</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n"responseText: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Cannot POST /user-create</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n"responseType: ""responseURL: "http://localhost:3030/user-create"responseXML: nullstatus: 404statusText: "Not Found"timeout: 0upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload {onloadstart: null, onprogress: null, onabort: null, onerror: null, onload: null, …}withCredentials: false[[Prototype]]: XMLHttpRequeststatus: 404statusText: "Not Found"[[Prototype]]: Object[[Prototype]]: Errorconstructor: ƒ AxiosError(message, code, config, request, response)toJSON: ƒ toJSON()isAxiosError: true[[Prototype]]: Object
App.js:29
```

Here is the Client React APP.JS:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Axios from 'axios';

const shortid = require('shortid');

//Create Referral Code
let refShortID = shortid.generate();

function App() {

  //Input Stuff
  const [uEmail, setuEmail] = useState("We need to verify that you're real...");
  const [friendRef, setfriendRef] = useState("Kaboomski");

  let uEmailonChange = (event)  => {
    const uEmailValue = event.target.value;
    setuEmail(uEmailValue);
  };
  let friendRefonChange = (event)  => {
    const newfriendRefValue = event.target.value;
    setfriendRef(newfriendRefValue);
  };

  const submitNewUser = () => {
    //Console Log Vars on Submit
    console.log(uEmail + friendRef + refShortID);
    
    //Post to Server Side API
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3030/user-create", {
      referBy: friendRef,
      referId: refShortID,
      eMail: uEmail,
    }).then(() => {
      alert('successful insert')
    });    
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">    
        <h1>Welcome to Starseed Command</h1>
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      </header>
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="formEmail"
          placeholder="enter your email address..."
          onChange ={uEmailonChange}
        />
        <label>Friend's Referral Code: </label>
        <input 
          type="text"
          name="formReferby"
          placeholder="enter friend's referral code..." 
          onChange={friendRefonChange} 
        />
        <button onClick={submitNewUser}>Sign Up</button>
        <a href="http://t.me/StarseedCommandRewards_bot">
        <button>Join Our Instagram</button>
        </a>
        <h1>New Account Regisrtation</h1>
        <h2>Your Email:<span className="blue"> {uEmail}</span></h2>
        <h2>Your Friend's Referral Code:<span className="blue">{friendRef}</span></h2>
        <h2>Your Starseed Command Rewards Code:<span className="blue"> {refShortID}</span></h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the Server Node Index.JS:

```
const express = require ("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const mysql = require ('mysql');
const cors = require('cors')

//Set allowed Domains for API
const allowedDomains = ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://localhost:3030']

//Console Log allowedDomains
console.log(allowedDomains);

const db = mysql.createPool({
    host: "freesqldatabase.com",
    database:"sqlxyzFAKE",
    user: "sqlxyzFAKE",
    password: "sqlxyzFAKE",
});

app.use (bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(express.json())
app.use (cors({
    origin: allowedDomains,
    credentials: true
}))


app.post("/create-user"), 
(req, res)=> {

        const referBy = req.body.referBy
        const referId = req.body.referId
        const eMail = req.body.eMail

    db.query(
        "INSERT INTO users (referBy, referId, eMail) VALUE (?,?,?)",
        [referBy, referId, eMail], 
        (err, result) => {
            console.log(result);
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.send("Values Inserted");
            }
    });
}

//Working MYSQL Database Test
//app.get('/', (rec, res) => {
//    const sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO users (referby, referid, email) VALUES ('Kaboomski', 'shortID!@#!@#', 'myname@mail.com');"
//    db.query(sqlInsert, (err, result) => {
//        res.send("sent to db - Kaboomski!!!");
//
//    } )
//   
//    console.log (db)
//});
    

app.listen(3030, () => {
    console.log("Hurray! Your server side host is running on port 3030");
});
```

Thank you!

-00g

Comment: This error has nothing to do with mysql,this is a http communication error.

Comment: okay, thank you for the clarification and reviewing my question.  It is related in the app once it works and any help is appreciated.

 I am still not familiar with how to solve the error, which would allow the app to then post.